# Order array based on last name in ASC and DESC order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a table which orders in ASC and DESC order, however this only orders the table rows which are shown as I only show 15 rows at a time. So I'm now wanting to use the array to sort so that I can use the hidden rows as well but i'm getting an error as followed:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

**What i've got so far:**

```js
// Variables for limiting Patients on show
var patientsToShow = 15;

// Stored Patient List
var storedPatientList = [{"RESPONSE": "OK"}, {"RECORDS": {"LastName":"Ashley", "LastName":"Jamie", "LastName":"Smith"}}];

// On page select initialize functions
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  
    $(".sortable").click(function() 
    {
        // Create a new array to store the Patients at multiple points
        var originalPatientList = new Array();
        var newPatientList = new Array();
        var patientTableRecord = '';

        originalPatientList = storedPatientList;

        if (originalPatientList.RESPONSE == "OK")
        {
            var clickedSorting = $(this).hasClass('orderNameByASC') ? 'orderNameByDESC' : 'orderNameByASC';
            $('.sortable').removeClass('orderNameByASC').removeClass('orderNameByDESC');
            $(this).addClass(clickedSorting);

            var columnIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
            var tableBody = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
            var tableRow = tableBody.find("tr");

            originalPatientList.sort(function(a, b) 
            {
                var aText = $(a).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text();
                var bText = $(b).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text();

                // get the last name. May need to do something more complicated
                // if you want to skip middle names
                var A = aText.substr(aText.indexOf(' '));
                var B = bText.substr(bText.indexOf(' '));

                if (clickedSorting == 'orderNameByASC')
                {
                    return A.localeCompare(B);
                }
                else
                {
                    return B.localeCompare(A);
                }
            });

                        // If so, loop through the old Patient list
            for(var i = 0; i < originalPatientList.RECORDS.length; i++)
            {
                var currentRecord = originalPatientList.RECORDS[i];

                // If so, push the Patient into the new list
                newPatientList.push("<tr><td>" + currentRecord["LastName"] + "</td></tr>");                
            }
        }

        $.each(tableRow, function(key, value) 
        {
            tableBody.append(value);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* Hidden Patient Notice */

.patientListHiddenNotice {
  display: none;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* No Patients Found Notice */

.patientListEmptyNotice {
  display: none;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#dataTables-example th.orderNameByASC:after {
  content: '▲';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: green;
}
#dataTables-example th.orderNameByDESC:after {
  content: '▼';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
  <!-- Patient listing table -->
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="sortable orderNameByASC">Patients</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="patientListHiddenNotice">
      <h4><span class='recordsHidden'>0</span> records hidden, use search field above...</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="patientListEmptyNotice">
      <h4>No records found</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I'm not looking to use anything like datatables**

Comment: Don't use the `var arr = new Array()` syntax - it's deprecated in favour of `var arr = []`

Comment: @JonathanBrooks Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that the data you're trying to sort comes from a database? 
Why not simply sort the data in your query, and then update the table using AJAX?

Because sorting only a subset is generally not a good idea, that way you could get a page that lists 'Alice, Charlie, Egon and Yann' and when you move to the next subset you list 'Bob, Derrick, Fred and William'. This is not the behaviour that you're looking for.

If you have the entire data-set in javascript, just use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), to sort the entire set, and then re-render the entire table using the sorted set.

Comment: Currently I'm using Ajax to get the data, then I store the data returned back from my database and then I want to sort the Array that the data is stored in.

Answer (score -3):

I would highly suggest you use https://www.datatables.net/ for these kind of problems. If you are opposed to the idea of using a third-party library to fix your problem, then I'd suggest you keep two lists. One is the full list of all records, the second one is a snippet of this list which only shows the top 15 hits for the sorting sequence applied.

Comment: I'm not looking to use anything like datatables, and could you give an example along side your explanation?